# Logstash Update a previous document in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

I am facing the following issue with writing logstash configuration.
The input files look something like this

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "item.status":"PENDING_APPROVAL",
  "originalId": 1,
  "process": "Item creation"
}
```

The item `id : 1` gets inserted into elastic-search. The same item is later approved and the approval also generates a log with field originalId as 1 which says that the item with id 1 has been approved.

```
{
  "Id": 2,
  "item.status":"APPROVED",
  "originalId": 1,
  "process" : "Item approval"
}
```

My question here is how to update the status of the inserted data while also inserting the approved log so that the resultant data in elastic-search should be like

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "item.status":"APPROVED",
  "originalId": 1,
  "process": "Item creation"
}
{
  "Id": 2,
  "item.status":"APPROVED",
  "originalId": 1,
  "process" : "Item approval"
}
```

I did try `doc_as_upsert` method in logstash.
The `status` field gets updated **but the approval document doesn't get inserted**. How do I achieve that?

I'm pretty new to logstash, so any help is much appreciated :).

Here is my logstash conf.

```
  input {
  file {
     //input file location
  }
}

filter {

    json{
        skip_on_invalid_json => true
        source => "message"
    }

    if ( [process] in  ["Item approval"] ) {

       prune{
                whitelist_names => ["item.status","originalId"]
           } 

    }
}

output {

    elasticsearch {
                action => "update"
                hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
                index => "items"
                document_id => "%{originalId}"
                doc_as_upsert => true
            }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use two elasticsearch outputs. One to do the upsert, one to index the document.

```
elasticsearch {
    action => "update"
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "items"
    document_id => "%{originalId}"
    doc_as_upsert => true
}
elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "items"
    document_id => "%{Id}"
}
```

If you want the complete document to go to one output and only the whitelisted fields to the other then use pipeline-to-pipeline communications with a [forked-path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html#forked-path-pattern) pattern. Write the document to two pipelines, in one do the whitelist and the upsert, in the other just index the document.

Comment: I understand, but won't the second elastic-search output insert only white-listed fields? I have other fields related to approval process and they get lost. So is there any way to update the status field without having to whitelist? Or Can we ignore the whitelist when the second elastic-search output executes?

Comment: Updated to answer this.